# CMD + ` to switch between windows on Turkish keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, window-manager

I have a Macbook Pro with Turkish keyboard layout and I haven't been able to find what the equivalent shortcut combination for <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to switch between windows, especially on Chrome.

Does anyone knows what that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts` to discover this setting on standard Turkish keyboard: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.
[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]